# how to express a range of numbers (11%-20%) in a battery notification script

Tags: acpi, battery, zenity

I'd like to have a script that notifies me when my battery is at or above 90%, at or below 20%, and at or below 10%. I cobbled together the following, substituting zenity for notify-send so that I receive a notification that will show up if I'm watching a movie in full screen mode. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to express a range of numbers (11%-20%), only "ge" and "le." It would also be nice to have the notifications stop after I've plugged in or unplugged. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Battery level notification
while true
do
    battery_level=$(acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)')

    if [ "$battery_level" -ge 90 ]; then
       zenity --info --title="Battery is at or above 90%" --text="Unplug adapter now" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    fi

    sleep 180 # 180 seconds or 3 minutes

    if [ "$battery_level" -le 20 ]; then
       zenity --info --title="Battery is at or below 20%" --text="Plug in adapter now" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    fi

    sleep 120 # 120 seconds or 2 minutes

    if [ "$battery_level" -1e 10 ]; then
       zenity --warning --title="Battery is at or below 10%" --text="PLUG IN ADAPTER NOW!!!" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    fi

    sleep 60 # 60 seconds or 1 minute

done
```

It should be fairly clear from the above that I don't really know what I'm doing! (I'm not even sure what language this is written in) Using Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Battery level notification
while true
do
    battery_level="$1"

    if [ "$battery_level" -ge 90 ]; then
        #Battary level is 90 or higher
        zenity --info --title="Battery is at or above 90%" --text="Unplug adapter now" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    elif [ "$battery_level" -le 20 ] && [ "$battery_level" -ge 11 ]; then
        #Battary level is between 11 and 20
        zenity --info --title="Battery is at or below 20%" --text="Plug in adapter now" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    elif [ "$battery_level" -le 10 ]; then
        #Battary level is less or equal 10
        zenity --warning --title="Battery is at or below 10%" --text="PLUG IN ADAPTER NOW!!!" --icon-name='battery' --height=50 --width=200
    fi

    sleep 60 # 60 seconds or 1 minute

done
```

You can check multiple conditions with the `&&` characters. 
And `elif` stands for else if. If the first condition doesn't work he will check the second, if this doesn't work too he will check the third and so on.